# Adding Theme or Skin to already existing Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net

Its already asked Question but the answer seems to be in a different way Thats why iam posting it again

I had a winform application on .net 4  its development is completed and My management had concluded that this application needs a little bit more "Colourful" they suggested that there should be a option for the user to select the theme for the application.

Now after going through the answers of all the previous questions of the same type i came to know that I had to change the Code of all the 150 forms of the project.Is there any other way that I can accomplish this process

Comment: You could use a 3.th party Winforms / controls vendor. I would suggest [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/): [look here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2534)

Comment: But its costly isn't it?

Comment: Well.. yes, and if all you need from them is the Theme engine... its properly not the right choice.